# Python / Pandas - Transform phone numbers from float to ints in a column with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column with floats and NaNs.
Those are phone numbers and they look strange as floats (it gets a ".0" in the end, and the phone number looks like this 5551981180099.0). I tried to use `df['phone'].astype(int)` to fix that, however it bugs with the NaNs and I get a "can't convert NAs to int" error.

So I went to brutal force with this:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if pd.isnull(df['phone'][i]) == False:
        df['phobe'][i] = int(df['phone'][i])
```

But when I `print(type(df['phone'][i]))` it tells me that it is still a `class 'numpy.float64'`.

I tried everything to turn that into something else to make the phone numbers look nice (turn into string and take the two last characters out, apply astype(str), astype(int), etc) but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `NaN` values with `int`, by design all values are convert to `float`s.

You can replace `NaN` to some `int` and then is possible convert column to `int`.

```
df['phone'] = df['phone'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Or remove `NaN` rows first:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['phone'])
df['phone'] = df['phone'].astype(int)
```

Or replace all values to `str` and then remove `.0`, but then get strings `NaN` (not missing value):

```
df['phone'] = df['phone'].astype(str).str.replace('\.0', '')
```

Last if need remove last 2 chars use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df['phone'] = df['phone'].astype(str).str.replace('\.0', '').str[:-2]
```

Comment: `.` is a wildcard for the replace function. It should be escaped with a ` \ `